# Vue & Pinia - Is this the standard data flow between Pinia store and Vue composables and components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I'm coming from a React background, but I've been working with Vue, Pinia, and Nuxt for several months and still find their documentation confusing / incomplete.

[image]

- Components pull state from Pinia stores (and possibly manage some local state).
- Pinia stores can use / reuse the logic in Composables.
- Composables don't read in data from from Pinia Stores inside the Composable function bodies. However, data from Pinia stores may be passed to Composable functions as function parameters. (This is because, in a complex application, lots of Composables reading multiple Pinia Stores, and then those Stores using those Composables, leads to circular references).

This part may be more preference than standard.

- Components *can* use / reuse logic from Composables — but they shouldn't because, in a complex application, this could get messy / confusing because data is not flowing in a consistent pattern.

Comment: It shouldn't be really different from React in this regard, except that global state in Vue isn't necessarily tied to app instance, like it would with React context (although it's a good practice to be compatible with Nuxt). Pinia store is represented by "use" composable, it's a special case of them. "leads to circular references" - isn't really a problem, unless it occurs within the same store action. It's a problem that a composable is generally allowed only in comp setup function, similarly to React. Some of them (store and composition api fns) are allowed outside, this should be verified

Comment: The composables are designed for wrapping logic concerns and reuse if needed. It is not messy/confusing when reusing composable since they are just functions. It's just you have not gotten familiar with it yet